# What is the YouTube's PlayerState during pre-roll ad?

Tags: flash, youtube-api

The Flash YouTube API getPlayerState() method has 6 possible values:

- -1 (unstarted)
- 0 (ended)
- 1 (playing)
- 2 (paused)
- 3 (buffering)
- 5 (video cued).

The manual reads:

> When the player first loads a video, it will broadcast an unstarted
>   (-1) event. When a video is cued and ready to play, the player will
>   broadcast a video cued (5) event. In your code, you can specify the
>   integer values or you can use one of the following namespaced
>   variables.

Consider this:

1. The player is CUED waiting for user interaction.
2. User clicks play
3. Pre-roll video ad starts to play

**What state is the player in during the pre-roll ad? How do I know an ad is being played?**

Comment: Can't you just make a dev player that throws player info every second or something so you can watch the player state in realtime as you play with it?

Comment: That will be my second action. You know, they have this button there that reads "Get Help". I clicked it and it landed me here. What a surprise! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did the legwork for you at https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Cuing a video with a preroll and then clicking Play leads to:

1. onStateChange event: Player state changed to: "-1" (undefined)
2. cueVideoById(cggNqDAtJYU, parseInt(0), default);
3. onStateChange event: Player state changed to: "5" (video cued)
4. onStateChange event: Player state changed to: "2" (paused)

So the video's state is PAUSED (2) while the ad is playing. Additionally, calls to playVideo() or pauseVideo() will be no-ops during a preroll.

Comment: Thanks, the reward is yours. The real reason why I raised this question was that I hoped someone from YouTube will come to realise that this is far from optimal. The paused state can not clearly identify the ad playback. On pause, for instance, the seek bar is still active, on ad you need to deactivate it, how do you tell the difference?

Comment: Jeff, would the same hold true during a mid-roll? Also, can you clarify what you mean by, "Additionally, calls to playVideo() or pauseVideo() will be no-ops during a preroll"

Comment: I mean that calls to those methods will be effectively ignored if they're made while an ad is playing. And I haven't tested against mid-roll ads, but I'd strongly suspect that they behave identically.