# YouTube iFrame API: events fired for TrueView InStream Ads (video ads)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Which events are fired when a [TrueView InStreams ad](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1205675) starts and ends?

The [YouTube iFrame API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) does not give any hint about it.

I need to know when the real video starts.

As these ads are shown "randomly", I cannot make any test.

One possible answer could be a way to systematically show these ads (and thus allow testing).

Comment: I think this is already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464499/what-is-the-youtubes-playerstate-during-pre-roll-ad

Comment: Seems right. Though, there's no perfect solution :/
(you should put the link as an answer so I can give you the bounty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems already answered by [What is the YouTube's PlayerState during pre-roll ad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464499/what-is-the-youtubes-playerstate-during-pre-roll-ad).

Basically, when ads starts state changes from `-1` (undefined) to `5` (cued) then `2` (paused).

I guess it's possible to know if ads on by looping (`setInterval` and such) and checking if state strictly goes from `-1`, `5` and finally `2`.

Starting check with `-1` secures from confusing ad's start/end from other event likes "cueing next video", etc.

However, this isn't a perfect solution as ads can start at the end of the video...