# Youtube API detecting advertisements

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to detect a youtube advertisement, when it is playing and also when it ends?

Something like:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
   if(event.data == advertisement) {
      console.log("Advertisement is playing");
   }
   if(event.data == advertisementIsOver) {
      console.log("Advertisement has finished playing");
   }
}
```

I see the question here:

[What is the YouTube's PlayerState during pre-roll ad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464499/what-is-the-youtubes-playerstate-during-pre-roll-ad)

And am wondering if there are any updates to the youtube api? Also, can someone provide some code of a youtube advertisement detector? I am not sure how one reliably catches when an advertisement is playing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener). It is stated that you can use [`onAdStarted()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener#onAdStarted()) which is called when playback of an advertisement starts.

Here is a related [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/DFKQhcP-k6E) and [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/) which might help.

Comment: This appears to only be for the youtube android api. Do you know of any support for onAdStarted() or any equivalent method for the youtube iframe?

Comment: @shell same issue here: did you find a way that can be applied to te youtube web iframe api?

Comment: @shell maybe with the youtube data api which wuld be more stable than other css /js based solutions*

Answer (score 10):

A little late but better late than never...

I'm currently developing a chrome extension specifically targeted towards YouTube video playback manipulation. This is one method I've found to detect whether an ad is playing:

**Note**: All classes I use and Id's are subject to change as YouTube developers change them.

1) Get the html5 video element first: `var mainVideo = document.getElementByClassName("html5-main-video")`. No element Id for it at the moment but it always has the class `html5-main-video`.

2) Set an event handler for when the video is ready to play that will check whether or not it's an ad and will be fired when a new video is loaded and ready to play `mainVideo.oncanplay = isVideoAnAd`.

3) When an ad is playing the progress bar is yellow or more specifically `rgb(255, 204, 0)` and this property is easily comparable using jQuery

```
function isVideoAnAd () {
     if($(".ytp-play-progress").css("background-color") === "rgb(255, 204, 0)
     {
        return true;
     }}
```

For more reliable results you can also check the `movie_player` elements `classList` to see if it `contains("ad-showing")`. By the way, `movie_player` is the id.

**Tip**: I found all of this with inspect element

This is really the only reliable way I've found to detect ads without having to dive into the YouTube API.