# On a YouTube video page, how do I check if the video is currently playing an ad or the actual video via javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, youtube, browser-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension that displays content synced with the video.

I need to wait until the viewer finishes the ad/midroll before displaying the content. How do I do something such as the following via javascript?

```
if (videoOnAd == true) {
//do something
} else {
//do something else
}
```

Thanks in advance!

- Kyler

Comment: oh yeah sorry about that. I've edited the question. I just need to check if the video is currently playing an ad or if it's playing the video. Thank you for the correction :3

Comment: video's emit lots of events, you should look into those events to see if there's a suitable one

Comment: I searched stack overflow (did you do that before asking?) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985456/youtube-api-detecting-advertisements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution!

```
if (document.querySelector("div.ad-showing")) {
           //Ad is active as a video 
           console.log("this is an ad")
        }
        else {
console.log("the video is playing")
}
}
```

Enjoy everyone!