# Knowing if a YouTube video is on an ad using content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am making a chrome extension that needs to know if a YouTube video is being played, paused, had a duration change, and if it is on an ad. I figured out how to do everything except knowing if it is on an advertisement. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63749340/on-a-youtube-video-page-how-do-i-check-if-the-video-is-currently-playing-an-ad) which was of some help, however, if I were to put this in my content script it would only run once and I want it to constantly check if there is an ad (since ads can happen in the middle of a video.

I am fairly new to Javascript, but I do understand the concepts of listeners and I would use a listener in this case, however, I do not know how to do that in this case because the div does not emit an event, it either exists or is null. Are there any other ways of doing that?

Comment: look for youtube video api events - I'm pretty sure there is one - I just can't find it

Answer (score 0):

+1 to looking at YouTube video API events. Here's that page [0].

I haven't tried this myself, but I would start with the `onStateChange` event, because I suspect that an ad is a separate video from the desired video content itself. So there could be two "video cued" or "5" values fired. But, again, I haven't tried it myself. Good luck!

[0] https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

Comment: Ok I will try and do that in a bit, and will edit this comment if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setInterval` to detect ads continuously. This is a way without having to looking for API.

```js
// According to the post you provided
function detectAds() {
  return !!document.querySelector("div.ad-showing");
}

let timer;

function listen() {
  timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (detectAds()) { /* do something */ }
  }, 1000); // runs every second
}

function unlisten() {
  if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
}
```